2014 silverado 1500 power window wiring diagram
I am working on adding tow mirrors to my 2014 silverado 1500 work truck. It cam from the factory with no power mirrors I am looking for the door jam, bcm and door switch.
The truck came from the factory with power windows and locks. I am in need of the wiring harness for the power mirror switch, defrost, bcm and door jams. Any help is appreciated.
I have the wiring diagram for the tow mirrors I purchased.

Any help is appreciated.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
